# Java recursive maze oscillating between positions without stack overflow

Tags: java, recursion, branch

I have a static method `getPath( int r, int c, int[][] maze, String path )` that returns a string value of the path to solve a maze. I have read all of the other posts on recursive mazes but I have been working on this problem for days and I cannot figure out why it's not working. Using the debugger has not helped find a solution. If anyone can find the answer please share. The following code works for some maps perfectly, however it does not work for one specific map:

```
int[][] maze = { {  0, 0,97, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                 {  0,99, 0,99,99,99, 0,99,99,99 },
                 {  0, 0,99, 0,99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                 { 99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99, 0 },
                 { 99, 8,99, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0,99, 0 },
                 { 99, 0,99, 0,99,99,99, 0,99, 0 },
                 {  0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0,99, 0,99, 0 },
                 {  0,99,99,99,99,99,99, 0, 0, 0 },
                 {  0, 2, 1, 0,99, 0, 0,99,99, 4 },
                 {  0,99,99, 0, 0, 0, 0,98,99, 0 } };
```

Here is the code:

```
public static String getPath( int r, int c, int[][] maze, String path ) { 

    if( maze[r][c] == 98 ) { return path; } // base case: solution

    maze[r][c] = 11; // marks current position as visited

    if( available( r, c + 1, maze ) // checks if east is available
            && getPath( r, c + 1, maze, path ) != null ) {  // recursive call
        maze[r][c] = 0; // unmarks the current position
        return getPath( r, c + 1, maze, path + "E" ); // recursive return call
    }
    if( available( r + 1, c, maze ) // checks if south is available
            && getPath( r + 1, c, maze, path ) != null ) {
        maze[r][c] = 0;
        return getPath( r + 1, c, maze, path + "S" );
    }
    if( available( r, c - 1, maze) // checks if west is available
            && getPath( r, c - 1, maze, path ) != null ) {
        maze[r][c] = 0;
        return getPath( r, c - 1, maze, path + "W" );
    }
    if( available( r - 1, c, maze ) // checks if north is available
            && getPath( r - 1, c, maze, path ) != null ) {
        maze[r][c] = 0;
        return getPath( r - 1, c, maze, path + "N" );
    }   

    maze[r][c] = 0; // there are no more moves to make

    return  null; // path does not have a solution here
}

public static boolean available( int r, int c, int[][] maze ) {
    return ( r >= 0 && r < maze.length )
            && ( c >= 0 && c < maze[0].length )
            && ( (  maze[r][c] >= 0 && maze[r][c] <= 9 ) || maze[r][c] == 98 );

}
```

(97 is the start, 98 is the end, 99 is blocked, and 0 <= i <= 9 is available)

Comment: You said you debugged it. What did you find?

Comment: And I can't recall if C++ compilers are capable of TRO, or if this even qualifies for it, but you're probably running into an infinite loop scenario somewhere. Have to let it run for awhile and verified that it doesn't keep consuming resources?

Comment: @Carcigenicate when I debugged it eventually came to an infinite loop like you say, where the position oscillated between (6,0) and (6,1). It shouldn't be allowed to do this but I am assuming that the unmarking statement after all of the direction tests is causing this. However when I block off a section that doesn't have any moves leading to the solution, the final return value always returns null. I am probably not blocking off the wrong positions correctly. When just compiling the program, the program keeps running without throwing an out of memory exception.